# How similar are large cardinals, over $L$?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals, constructibility

*EDIT: Joel's answer shows that no $\Sigma_2$ large cardinal property will do the job - however, $\Pi_2$ properties (such as [unfoldability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unfoldable_cardinal) and its relatives) may still be useful.*

---

*Throughout this question, I'm working in "$V=L$". So when I say "large cardinal," I mean "**small** large cardinal".*

Informally, I want to ask: How much of the "$L$-theory" of a cardinal does a large cardinal property imply? That is, if I know that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both have some large cardinal property $(*)$, what sorts of (not necessarily first-order) sentences do I know that $L_\alpha$ and $L_\beta$ agree about?

Formally, fix an ordinal $\gamma$. Say that a large cardinal property $(*)$ is "$\gamma$-decisive" if whenever $\alpha, \beta$ have property $(*)$, we have $$L_{\alpha+\gamma}\equiv L_{\beta+\gamma}.$$ My question is:

> What are some examples of $\gamma$-decisive large cardinal properties?

(CAVEAT: Obviously *any* large cardinal property can be arbitrarily decisive: suppose it has no instances, or exactly one! So really I want to know about large cardinal properties whose decisiveness can be *proved* in ZFC+V=L, or some strengthening thereof that does not limit the number of relevant large cardinals.)

Note that decisiveness looks a lot (at least to me) like indescribability; however, indescribability doesn't quite seem to do the job, unless I'm missing something.

---

I'm also interested in decisiveness *with parameters* - e.g. for a finite tuple of sets $\overline{c}\in L$, say that a large cardinal property $(*)$ is $\gamma$-decisive over $\overline{c}$ if whenever $\alpha,\beta$ have property $(*)$ with $\overline{c}\in L_\alpha\cap L_\beta$, we have $$(L_\alpha, \overline{c})\equiv(L_\beta,\overline{c}).$$ But understanding the parameter-free version should come first, and besides, I imagine the situations aren't too different.

By contrast, something potentially interesting happens if we allow, not tuples of *elements of $L$*, but tuples $\overline{C}$ of *subsets of $L$* which are in $V$ but not necessarily $L$ - coded as unary predicates, of course. A really overkill example of this would be the $0^\#$ as a unary predicate, but already tamer examples could be interesting. For instance, suppose $\overline{C}$ is a finite sequence of mutually Cohen reals over $L$ - then what are some $\gamma$-decisive *over $\overline{C}$* large cardinal properties? But this question seems much broader, and much harder, so I'll merely mention it as a curiosity. (Note that in this context, detrivializing things becomes a bit trickier, so this is a more informal question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer**. I claim that none of the familiar large cardinal
notions consistent with $V=L$ are provably $\gamma$-decisive for
any $\gamma$. This includes the cases of wordly cardinals,
inaccessible cardinals, uplifting cardinals, Mahlo cardinals weakly
compact cardinals, $\Pi^n_m$-indescribable cardinals, totally
indescribable cardinals, unfoldable cardinals and all the others.

First, as a warm-up, let's handle the case of $\Sigma_2$-definable
large cardinal notions.

**Theorem.** If a large cardinal notion LC is $\Sigma_2$-definable
and there are a proper class of them in $L$, then there is no
$\gamma$ for which they are $\gamma$-decisive.

**Proof.** To see this, fix any $\gamma$, and let $\kappa$ be the
least LC cardinal above $\gamma$. Note that both $\kappa$ and
$\gamma$ are definable in $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$, since $\kappa$ is
the largest cardinal of this structure, and $\gamma$ is least such
that $\kappa+\gamma$ does not exist. Further, since $\kappa$ was
the least LC cardinal above $\gamma$, it follows that
$L_{\kappa+\gamma}$ will agree that there are no such large
cardinals of that type in the interval $(\gamma,\kappa)$, since
$\Sigma_2$ definitions express locally verifiable properties (see
my blog post about [Local properties in set
theory](http://jdh.hamkins.org/local-properties-in-set-theory/)).
But the corresponding fact will not be true in $L_{\delta+\gamma}$
for some other much larger LC cardinal $\delta$, since once
$\delta$ is large enough, then $L_{\delta+\gamma}$ will think that
$\kappa$ is an LC cardinal. So $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$ is not
elementarily equivalent to all $L_{\delta+\gamma}$, and so the LC
large cardinal notion is not $\gamma$-decisive in this situation.
**QED**

Next, with a slightly stronger assumption on consistency, we can
handle the $\Pi_2$-definable notions.

**Theorem.** Assume that a large cardinal notion LC is
$\Pi_2$-definable and there are a sufficiently stationary proper
class of them in $L$, then there is no $\gamma$ for which they are
$\gamma$-decisive.

**Proof.** Fix any $\gamma$, and assume that the class of LC
cardinals in $L$ meets every $\Pi_2$-definable class club. Let
$C$ be the club of $\Sigma_2$-correct cardinals $\delta$, those for
which $V_\delta\prec_{\Sigma_2} V$. This is $\Pi_2$-definable. Let
$\kappa$ be the least LC cardinal in $C$ above $\gamma$. Note that
both $\kappa$ and $\gamma$ are definable in $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$.
Further, since $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_2$-correct, it must be a
beth-fixed-point, and so $L_\kappa=(V_\kappa)^L$. Since $L_\kappa$
is $\Sigma_2$-correct and hence also $\Pi_2$-correct, it is correct
about the LC cardinals below $\kappa$. And it is also correct about
the $\Sigma_2$-cardinals below $\kappa$. So by the minimality of
$\kappa$, the structure $L_\kappa$ can see that there is no
$\Sigma_2$-correct LC cardinal below $\kappa$ and above $\gamma$,
and this is part of the theory of $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$. But now, if
$\delta$ is a larger LC cardinal in $C$, then $L_{\delta+\gamma}$
will be able to see that there is a $\Sigma_2$-correct LC cardinal
below $\delta$. And so $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$ and $L_{\delta+\gamma}$
do not have the same theory. So the LC cardinals are not
$\gamma$-decisive. **QED**

Finally, we can use this idea to push through an argument for any
first-order definable large cardinal notion.

**Theorem.** No first-order definable large cardinal notion LC is
provably $\gamma$-decisive for any $\gamma$, if it is consistent
that there is a stationary proper class of LC cardinals in $L$.

**Proof.** Suppose that the LC large cardinal notion is
$\Sigma_n$-definable, and the class of LC cardinals in $L$ is
stationary with respect to all $\Pi_n$-definable class clubs. Fix
any $\gamma$, and let $\kappa$ be the least $\Sigma_n$-correct LC
cardinal above $\gamma$. There is such a $\kappa$ because the class
of $\Sigma_n$-correct ordinals is a $\Pi_n$-definable class club.
Both $\kappa$ and $\gamma$ are definable in $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$,
and $L_\kappa$ is correct about LC cardinals and about
$\Sigma_n$-correctness. So $L_\kappa$ will see no
$\Sigma_n$-correct LC cardinals above $\gamma$. But if we use a
much larger $\Sigma_n$-correct LC cardinal $\delta$, then
$L_\delta$ will see that $\kappa$ is a $\Sigma_n$-correct LC
cardinal above $\gamma$. So $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$ and
$L_{\delta+\gamma}$ will have different theories. **QED**

Comment: Sorry, I'm being slow: why will $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$ realize that $\kappa$ is indeed a large cardinal of the relevant type? (That is, I don't see why $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$ is correct about $\Sigma_2$ facts - what if the witness lives in $L_\mu$ for some $\mu>\kappa+\gamma$?)

Comment: I see, I didn't explain it correctly. The point is that $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$ won't have any of those cardinals below $\kappa$, but larger $L_{\delta+\gamma}$ will have such cardinals below $\delta$. I'll edit to explain it correctly.

Comment: Alright, now I don't see why $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$ won't have any of the relevant kind of cardinals: what if $L_{\kappa+\gamma}$ thinks some $\lambda<\kappa$ satisfies the $\Sigma_2$ property, even though it doesn't in reality? (I'm sure I'm just missing something basic.)

Comment: Every $L_\theta$ is $\Sigma_1$ elementary in $L$, for $\theta$ a cardinal, and so $\Sigma_2$-properties are upward absolute from $L_\kappa$.

Comment: Ouch, now I feel silly. Thanks! Since I can't think of any interesting $\Sigma_3$ large cardinal properties compatible with $V=L$, I've accepted.

Comment: There are many $\Pi_2$ large cardinal notions, consistent with $L$, such as: unfoldable, strongly unfoldable, and others. Those notions are defined by properties that involve a universal $\forall\theta$, and then having an embedding jumping beyond $\theta$. Violations of the property are locally verifiable, hence $\Sigma_2$, and so the notion is $\Pi_2$. My argument does not work for that case, so unfoldable might be a natural case.

Comment: Oh, I was unaware of those! Would it be rude of me to unaccept this answer, since I am interested in such properties now that I wiki them? (Of course I will not remove the upvote, this is a very nice answer!)

Comment: Incidentally, I have a blog post on $\Sigma_2$ properties and the idea of local verification. See http://jdh.hamkins.org/local-properties-in-set-theory/.

Comment: That looks really interesting, thanks!

Comment: Oh, sure, it is fine to unaccept.

Comment: Probably a naive question, but: if $\kappa$ is unfoldable, what can be said about the set of cardinals $\kappa$ "unfolds" to, that is, the set of $j(\kappa)$s for $j$ an unfoldability embedding?

Comment: In general, you cannot expect that this is even a cardinal---this would make a strictly stronger notion. So you can't expect to get $\gamma$-decisiveness by making them all align like that to each other.

Comment: By the way, uplifting cardinals are another $\Pi_2$ case, and very weak (below Mahlo in consistency strength).

Comment: I think I can prove now that if the class of unfoldable cardinals (or uplifting cardinals) is a stationary class (or even just stationary with respect to $\Sigma_2$-definable class clubs), then unfoldable cardinals cannot be $\gamma$-decisive for any $\gamma$. It's late now, but I'll post the details tomorrow.  This may generalize to any $\Pi_2$-definable large cardinal, which will cover essentially all the standard large cardinal concepts.

Comment: I think this idea will generalize beyond $\Pi_2$, so that there can be no $\gamma$-decisive first-order large cardinal notion, if there can be a stationary proper class of such cardinals. I'm going to sleep on it; check back tomorrow!

Comment: I made the update this morning. If this is correct, it seems to settle the issue.